# Division by zero in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

I've a problem which I can not fix in Laravel 5.1. I have "`Division by zero`" as an error in this code:

```
public static function GetAvgVisits()
    {
      $average_visits = DB::table('tracker_sessions')->where('is_robot', '=', 0)
                        ->whereRaw("created_at between '".Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()."' and '".Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()."'")
                        ->count(DB::raw('DISTINCT client_ip')) / (int)Carbon::now()->diff(Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())->format('%a') + 1;

      return round($average_visits);
    }
```

And I just can't find the correct solution. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Please do a dump of `DB::table('tracker_sessions')->where('is_robot', '=', 0)
                        ->whereRaw("created_at between '".Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()."' and '".Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()."'")
                        ->count(DB::raw('DISTINCT client_ip'))`

Comment: int(0) is what I get

Comment: Today is the first of the month, so 1-1=0. Try putting parenthesis around the last part of the query: ((int)Carbon::now()->diff(Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())->format('%a') + 1)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The division precedes the + 1, so if the + 1 is there to prevent a zero division, then add parentheses before / and after + 1:

```
public static function GetAvgVisits()
    {
      $average_visits = DB::table('tracker_sessions')->where('is_robot', '=', 0)
                        ->whereRaw("created_at between '".Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()."' and '".Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()."'")
                        ->count(DB::raw('DISTINCT client_ip')) / ((int)Carbon::now()->diff(Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())->format('%a') + 1);

      return round($average_visits);
    }
```

A bit hard to see, but i have added these:

> / **(** (int)Carbon::now()->diff(Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())->format('%a') + 1 **)**;